# MongoDB atomicity with Javers

Tags: mongodb, javers

I see that Javers mongo repository stores data in two different collections. Assuming that I am using Javers for auditing, and I am writing my domain objects to another collection, I wonder how atomicity is maintained across these persistence operations. Does Javers perform some kind of two-phase commits to maintain sanity between it's two internal collections? Does it provide hooks for the client application's persistence operations to be in sync with the audit logs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In MongoDB there are no transactions. All you have is atomic write on Document level (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).
JaVers doesn't implement any kind of "multi-document transactions" on the application side.

If you need SQL-like transactions, choose JaversSqlRepository with JPA EntityManager integration
(see https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#jpa-entity-manager-integration).

Comment: Why not something like this?https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: even if javers would implement this pattern to manage inserts to its two collections, it can't manage application's writes

Comment: @BartekWalacik checking if this answer is still valid, now that MongoDB support multi-document transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Javers supports MongoDB transactions:

If you use Spring Boot, then after declaring the MongoTransactionManager as described here:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-transactions#mongodb-configuration Javers will pick it up automatically.

If you are not using Spring Boot, then you can configure Javers as described here: https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#mongo-transactions.

Please note that if you configured Javes to write data into separate database then you can't configure transaction management easily or at all.